# Use Redis for Caching ONLY if an instance is found/exists?

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

I'd like to use Redis for caching, but I still want my service to be functional if a Redis instance isn't found at runtime.

Are there any examples of this in practice?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following in your AppHost Configure method

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    ...
    try
    {
        var redisManager = new PooledRedisClientManager("localhost:6379");
        // do some sort of test to see if we can talk to the redis server
        var client = redisManager.GetCacheClient();
        var fakeKey = "_________test_______";
        client.Add(fakeKey, 1);
        client.Remove(fakeKey);
                    // if it worked register the cacheClient
        container.Register(c => redisManager.GetCacheClient()).ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.None);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // fall back to in memory cache
        // Log some sort of warning here.
        container.Register<ICacheClient>(c => new MemoryCacheClient());
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: So this is good for startup, but doesn't fix the issue where Redis goes down during the service's uptime. This is probably related to my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618354/how-to-change-cacheclients-at-runtime-in-servicestack